# how to style single letter without addtional html tags

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to style "u" without surrounding it with additional tags?

something like

```
h1:first-letter{ font-size:200%; color:#8A2BE2}
```

"u" I would like to, say, add opacity to is here:

```
<div class="moto"><h1>it's all<br>abboutt<br>design</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could if there were an `nth-letter` selector, but there isn't. You aren't the first to have these typographical dreams, however. Try http://letteringjs.com/ which will automate this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Or, technically speaking, *tags* are not needed, but the character needs to be made the sole content of an *element*. You could do that with JavaScript, searching for the first occurrence of the character in some content, then manipulate the DOM tree. It’s easiest to do this using tags, though.